# Changing NSUserDefaults of a mac or iOS binary executable

Tags: disassembly, ios, osx, hopper

I have an executable of a mac or ios app. This app uses a value stored for a key in `NSUserDefaults` to change app's flow.

It looks something like below code,

```
If( value set in user details )
        show something 
else
        hide something
```

My question is how can I change the value stored for a key in `NSUserDefaults` using hopper disassembler ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values are stored in a plist file under ~/Library/Preferences (or ~/Library/Containers/.../ if sandboxed). You can find more information about it from [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/UserPreferences.html).

The easiest way to modify a value is to use the defaults program under terminal.

`defaults write <bundle identifier> <key> <value>`